# On initial boot of Pi 3B+ what config app is running?

Tags: pi-3b+

When you first start a 3B+, there is a configuration application that runs.  How can I restart that from the CLI?  I need to start that application to simulate the initial start.

Comment: look at the `cmdline.txt` before first boot ... that should give you a clue ... it's `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=7ee80803-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh`

Comment: @JaromandaX I think OP is talking about the GUI config wizard that was introduced not too long ago. Can't remember the name ATM

Comment: that's the problem with vague questions, there's more than one vague answer, @Dirk

Comment: @JaromandaX true. BTW the name of the GUI wizard is piwiz. Needs admin privileges. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-update-june-2018/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, which i discovered quite quickly after posting the question is:

```
$ piwiz &
```

which does NOT require root/sudo.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.